# Message in iOS drafts folder reappearing after deleting

Tags: ios, icloud, email

I tried to use my mac.com email address to send my Mom too many photos from my iPhone after Christmas, and the message failed to send. I gave up and sent the photos another way, but that email keeps reappearing in my drafts folder after I delete it. I've also tried sending it to myself after deleting the photos from the message, which made it go away, but it reappeared later.

Mail.app on my Mac shows no messages in the drafts folder. At some point I guess I'll log into mac.com and see if there is anything there (but I'm guessing there isn't since it isn't appearing in Mail.app.)

iOS 16.2

**Update**: I finally broke down and just resent the message without editing it. I thought that worked but this morning the message appeared again. I think this may just be a bug.